# MS Access Limit textbox/combobox input characters and length to Numbers

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I would like to limit the number of characters(numbers) user can enter into comboboxes on my form to 2, 4, 6, and 8 (4 combo boxes). I would also like to ensure that only numeric characters can be entered. I set the input Mask on each of my comboboxes to the appropriate expression (99, 9999, 999999, 99999999). I then set the default for each of my combobox to 0. The problems I ran into doing this is that '_' character appears as placeholder for missing   entries, and when I manually clear my combobox, an error message is thrown.

My goal is to try avoid using code for this. there is an example at the following link with code  but I would rather not add code. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210047

I would however appreciate suggestion on how I can get rid of the 'placeholder' and the error message. I also would appreciate information on what to set to get the combobox drop down to show, displaying filtered selections as user types into the combobox.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a numeric entry, are you not? You can set a validation rule.

Two digits

```
<100
```

Or

```
 >9 And <100
```

Three digits

```
<1000
```

Comment: for inputmask property in Access?

Comment: I thought you did not want place holders?

Comment: But isn't there a way to accomplish this using the inputmask property?

Comment: You cannot get rid of the place holders if you want to use an Input Mask, but you should be able to get rid of the error by using `Me.Combo0 = Null`

Comment: Where do I set this to Me.combo0 = Null? Also, if I set Me.combo0 = NULL would that not then force my combobox not to be populated from the rowsource?

Comment: You say you are having problems with clearing your combo, I thought you meant in code. What did you mean by clearing if you did not want "not to be populated from the rowsource"?

Comment: Each time I try to view my form, a pop up shows with message suggesting that there is an error in query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15388/discussion-between-remou-and-kobojunkie)

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown of a combo box can be achieved by code (sorry) with

```
Me.ControlName.SetFocus
Me.ControlName.Dropdown
```

Comment: Please Where in code do I need to add this for each of my combo boxes? I tried doing this in onload and in on change, but got errors each time.

Comment: You may use this wherever it's suitable. The main question is: When (i.e. in which situation) do you want the combobox to drop down? This can be the event `Form_Load`, or any button click event (e.g. `cmdMyButton_Click`).